# 'for' loop crashes when downloading from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I have 4 elements in my `NSMutableArray`. I have this neat code for downloading files and displaying the file's data in `UITextView` for testing purposes. Without the `for` loop, everything is fine. The code that gives me the problem is in this function:

```
- (void)complexDownload {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < downloadArray.count; i++) {
        if (isBusy == NO) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
            downloadURL = [downloadArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"URL is %@", downloadURL);
            NSLog(@"Downloading object at index %i", i);
            NSURL *url = downloadURL;
            NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                  timeoutInterval:60.0];

            NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

                if (theConnection) {
                    self.downloadData = [NSMutableData data];
                    isBusy = YES;
                    NSLog(@"Busy value in download cycle equals %i, downloading", isBusy);
                } else {
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
                    NSLog(@"Connection failed");
                    isBusy = NO;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I first thought that the problem might be in the `isBusy` `BOOL`, but even without the `if` condition the app crashes. The compiler gives me no error but this one:
[Here's the link for the big screenshot](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/7913/20121219064023pm.png).

The rest of the functions are as follows:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [downloadData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    self.dataTextView.text = dataString;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    NSLog(@"Download finished!");
    isBusy = NO;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}
```

All the NSLogged values are more than fine, the Array has got links and all the links are correct.

Comment: You should really use NSOperation class instead of doing like this

Comment: @Pierre I know, I've tried, the problem is that NSOperationQueue has got some limitations, I can't reorder the operations and I can't manage them thoroughly enough.

Comment: Or blocks. At any rate, do you have the full crash log or output? That usually points to the underlying problem. You can also add a breakpoint from exceptions. Go under the breakpoint tab and add a new exception breakpoint. That will stop on the line that is crashing you so you can figure out why.

Comment: @BillBurgess I've edited the post with the screenshot of the crash output.

Comment: Did you set an exception breakpoint? I guess yes. Sometimes it is a good idea to click on 'continue' once or twice or so. It may require some 'continue' clicks befor the actual error message is displayed on the debug console. However - look to the call stack. The exception is thrown somewhere in SGDownloader complexDownl... Click on that and you should see in which line of your coude the execption is thown. Please get back to us with that additional information.

Comment: Didn't read the whole thread through, but this should cause a range exception since your for loop iterates from 0 to array.count and accessing array[arrat.count] is beyond bounds. Should be array.count-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that at some point either `downloadArray[i]` is corrupt at some point, or it's not an NSUrl. The code crashes in `CFURLCopyAbsoluteURL()` called from `[NSURLRequest requestWithURL...]`.

Comment: You were right! The URL passed to the ivar was of type NSSstring and I didn't notice it because it was taken directly from NSArray.

Answer (score 1):

You take the async api [initWithRequest:delegate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/initWithRequest%3adelegate%3a) and try to make it synchronous by using *isBusy* flag. This approach is very wrong to begin with, the NSURLConnection class is smart enough, do don't need to use arbitrary flags if you use it properly.
You should seriously reconsider using NSOperations or GCD. If you're planning to do more complicated connectivity programming maybe you should consider using a third party framework like RestKit.

Comment: NSOperations have a lot of limitations and this approach, though it's really complex does in fact give some options over what's being downloaded and when.

Comment: I don't think it's complex, it is just misusing the NSURLConnection api, which is going to be source of confusion for whoever maintains or updates this code. The answer from Hermann addresses the api misuse though, so I'm glad you like it.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the for loop and the isBusy indicator. 
In `complexDownload` always process the first or the last (what ever is more suitable) object only and then remove it from the array. In `connectionDidFinish` invoke `complexDownload` again. Use `performSelector` for that. The wait time may even be 0.0f. By doing so your `downloadArray` would act as some sort of queue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the priceless advice! That's a great idea!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a problem with url-object in [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
It is not necessary to copy the URL in an extra object. Try this:

```
NSLog(@"URL is %@", [downloadArray objectAtIndex:i]);
NSLog(@"Downloading object at index %i", i);
NSURL *url = [downloadArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

(or add self. before downloadURL)

If your downloadArray contains NSStrings:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[downloadArray objectAtIndex:i]];
```

I would recommend using external framework like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is great but it hasn't been supported for a long time. I've been told that https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking is a good to use these days.

Comment: Yes that's right, the last commit for ASIHTTPRequest is 5 months ago! Thanks for this alternative, I will test this in the current project.